Authenticating a user using Client Certificates on Symfony API-Platform and Nginx fails with SSL credentials not found
I have a Symfony API Platform appliaction that is served by NGINX. I am trying to secure access to the API's using Client certificates. I have provided the relevant details of the Client certificate below
sridhar@sridhar-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:$ openssl x509 -text -in client.crt -noout
    Certificate:
        Data:
            Version: 3 (0x2)
            Serial Number:
                39:c9:eb:c3:ef:4c:37:c8:16:49:ac:04:10:f0:80:a9:91:6b:8f:ec
            Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
            Issuer: C = IN, ST = Tamilnadu, L = Royapettah, O = MyOrganization, OU = Division, CN = mydomain.co.in, emailAddress = security@mydomain.co.in
            Validity
                Not Before: Jun 19 09:00:45 2024 GMT
                Not After : Nov  1 09:00:45 2025 GMT
            Subject: C = IN, ST = TN, L = Nanganallur, O = Client Organization Name, emailAddress = prr@clientdomain.co.in
    

My aim is to pass the Subject email Address from Nginx to Symfony and have Symfony Security module check the user table for a matching email id to determine if the visitor is allowed to access the API. To achieve this I have the following in the NGINX vhost configuration file
ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/myroot_CA.pem;
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_verify_depth 1;
location / {
    fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_S_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    expires max;                      
}

I am presuming that NGINX has populated $ssl_client_s_dn variable with the contents of the certificate Subjec. In this case
Subject: C = IN, ST = TN, L = Nanganallur, O = Client Organization Name, emailAddress = prr@clientdomain.co.in

On the Symfony side my security.yaml file contains the following
security:
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            #provider: app_user_provider

            x509:
              provider: app_user_provider
              user: SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email
              credentials: SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
              user_identifier: emailAddress

I expect Symfony to pick up the user SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email from the SSL_CLIENT_S_DN credentials object and validate it against the email in the user entity. However what I see in the symfony dev.log is the following
[2024-08-07T15:00:22.430708+05:30] deprecation.INFO: User Deprecated: Since symfony/serializer 6.3: Not implementing the "NormalizerInterface::getSupportedTypes()" in "ApiPlatform\JsonLd\Serializer\ObjectNormalizer" is deprecated. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Since symfony/serializer 6.3: Not implementing the \"NormalizerInterface::getSupportedTypes()\" in \"ApiPlatform\\JsonLd\\Serializer\\ObjectNormalizer\" is deprecated. at /home/sridhar/ab-abs/vendor/symfony/serializer/Debug/TraceableNormalizer.php:37)"} []
[2024-08-07T15:00:22.433395+05:30] request.INFO: Matched route "api_entrypoint". {"route":"api_entrypoint","route_parameters":{"_route":"api_entrypoint","_controller":"api_platform.action.entrypoint","_format":"","_api_respond":"true","index":"index"},"request_uri":"http://ab-abs-ap.mydomain.co.in/api?q=api","method":"GET"} []
[2024-08-07T15:00:22.436073+05:30] security.DEBUG: Checking for authenticator support. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticators":1} []
[2024-08-07T15:00:22.436277+05:30] security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\X509Authenticator"} []
[2024-08-07T15:00:22.437619+05:30] security.DEBUG: Skipping pre-authenticated authenticator as a BadCredentialsException is thrown. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): SSL credentials not found: \"SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email\", \"SSL_CLIENT_S_DN\". at /home/sridhar/ab-abs/vendor/symfony/security-http/Authenticator/X509Authenticator.php:57)","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\X509Authenticator"} []
[2024-08-07T15:00:22.437862+05:30] security.DEBUG: Authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\X509Authenticator"} []

It seems that Symfony is unable to find the email and hence the authentication is failing. I have been scouring all Nginx and Symfony documentation and havent found a solution. Can some point out what could be wrong in my setup
